# Overuse of code highlighting

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

What is the consensus on the usage of code highlighting in the questions? I myself add it quite generously when it highlights actual pieces of code (keywords, variable names) in the text.

This time however I came to en edit which uses it for every tag https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8778051 . I tried to reject it as didn't even improve other things like capitalization or the word "constating", but others agreed with it.

Is that the right usage of highlighting?

Also, why I cannot edit a post, if there is a pending edit in review there?

Comment: I've seen _way_ worse. The example you linked still looks reasonable. I'd have accepted the edit, since it fixes a couple of problems with the post.

Comment: If it makes something better and something worse, reject and edit and preferably @ping the user explaining what they did wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried searching, but didn't find this one. I agree it improved something in the bad post, but made other things worse.

Comment: `Heh`, the `OP` put `them` right `back` after `@CodeCaster` removed `them`.  Stop `the` madness `please`, it `is` horrible `to` read.

Comment: @Hans I guess OP [was editing at the time they were removed](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31378986/4), there's merely two minutes in between the edits (and `@mentions` in backticks don't notify, apparently. :P).